# Where to keep Page Objects in a Maven project

Tags: testing, maven, selenium-webdriver

I'm using the [Page Objects approach with Selenium2](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects) and wondering the best way to organize the page objects in the Maven project structure.

I currently have a completely separate maven project module for functional testing, so I'm leaning towards putting the page objects in src/main/java of the test project and then the junit tests that use the page objects in src/test/java.  I guess the alternative is to put it all in src/test/java.

Any thoughts on the advantages/disadvantages to either approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use following in my project -

src.test.java..library > contains page objects
src.test.java..tests > contains test

Answer (score 0):

You can store all page object in properties file under resources and you can read those property file use it ( .properties extension)

Source/main/resources/homepage.properties